# Web3.js error: Uncaught ReferenceError: abi is not defined

Tags: web3js

(Working from the Lynda Ethereum course, a simple "approver" contact and UI)

This line:

> var ApprovalContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);

Is giving the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: abi is not defined
>       at index.html:117

Here is the full html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    <title>Our little escrow Dapp</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to escrow dapp.</h1>

    <h2>Send money through contract:</h2>
    <form id="contract-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Sender Address">Sender ETH Address</label>
        <input value="" type="text" class="form-control" id="fromAddress" aria-describedby="fromAddressHelp" placeholder="Enter your address" required="true">
        <small id="fromAddressHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your wallet address. Note: you will need to approve this with your private key.</small>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Receiver Address">Receiver ETH Address</label>
          <input value="0x2932b7A2355D6fecc4b5c0B6BD44cC31df247a2e" type="text" class="form-control" id="toAddress" aria-describedby="toAddressHelp" placeholder="Enter the receipient address" required="true">
          <small id="toAddressHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter the wallet address of the recipient.</small>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Amount">Amount</label>
            <input value="2" type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" aria-describedby="amountHelp" placeholder="Amount to send in ETH" required="true">
            <small id="amountHelp" class="form-text text-muted">How much you want to send in ETH.</small>
          </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <div id="deposit-result">Click the Submit button to deposit your ETH to the contract.</div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <h2>Balance:</h2>
    <form id="get-balance-form">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Balance</button>
      <div id="the-balance">Click Button to get the current contract balance.</div>
    </form>
    <h2>Approver:</h2>
    <form id="approver-form">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Approver</button>
      <div id="approver-display">Click Button to get the address of the approver.</div>
    </form>

    <form id="approve-form">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Approve Transaction</button>
      <div id="approval-display">Click the button to approve the transaction.</div>
    </form>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="web3.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





    <script>
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:9545");



if ( typeof web3 != 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(Web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9545"));
}


web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9545"));

var version = web3.version;

console.log("using version: " + version);   


    </script>










    <script>

      // change this to the ACTUAL contract address that you created on truffle migrate
      var contractAddress = "0x2c2b9c9a4a25e24b174f26114e8926a9f2128fe4";
      if ( typeof web3 != 'undefined' ) {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        $('#fromAddress').val('0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732');
      } else { // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9545"));
        //web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9545"));
        $('#fromAddress').val(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
      }
      //var Web3 = require('web3');
      //var web3 = new Web3();

      var version = web3.version;
      console.log("Using web3 version: " + version);

      var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:9545");

var ApprovalContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
var ApprovalContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

      var ApprovalContract = new Web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);

      // script to show the contract
      console.log(ApprovalContract);

      //make sure that addresses are legit
      $('#contract-form').submit(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var fromAddress = $('#fromAddress').val();
        var toAddress = $('#toAddress').val();
        var amount = $('#amount').val();
        if (web3.utils.isAddress(fromAddress) != true) {
          alert('You did not enter a correct ethereum address for the sender address.');
          return;
        }
        if (web3.utils.isAddress(toAddress) != true) {
          alert('You did not enter a correct ethereum address for the recipient address.');
          return;
         }
        // make sure the ETH is > 0
        if (amount == 0){
          alert('You must send more than 0 ETH');
          return;
         }
      // all is good, let's call our contract deposit
      ApprovalContract.methods.deposit(toAddress).send({from: fromAddress, gas: 100000, value:  web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'ether')},
          function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              console.log('error: ' + error);
              $('#deposit-result').html('<b>Error: </b>' + error);
            }
            else {
            $('#deposit-result').html('Success TX: <b>' + result + '</b>');
            }
          });
    });


    $('#get-balance-form').submit(function() {
      event.preventDefault();

    web3.eth.getBalance(contractAddress,
          function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              console.log('error: ' + error);
            }
            else {
              console.log('balance: ' + result);
              $('#the-balance').html('<b>Current Balance: </b>' + web3.utils.fromWei(result));
            }
          });
        });

  //  });
        $('#approve-form').submit(function() {
          event.preventDefault();

          ApprovalContract.methods.approve().call({from: '0xC5fdf4076b8F3A5357c5E395ab970B5B54098Fef', gas: 100000},
              function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                  console.log('error: ' + error);
                }
                else {
                  console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                  $('#approval-display').html('Transaction Approved. TX: <b>' + result + '</b>');
                }
              });
        });
        $('#approver-form').submit(function() {
          event.preventDefault();

          ApprovalContract.methods.viewApprover().call(
              function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                  console.log('error: ' + error);
                }
                else {
                  console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                  $('#approver-display').html('Approver Address: <b>' + result + '</b>');
                }
              });
        });
    </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error says it all. Your smart contract abi definition is not defined in the javascript. You can read more about abi definition [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/compiling-smart-contracts-abi/). And btw your code looks a bit of a mess. Replace the 3 definitions of the contract inferfaces:

```
var ApprovalContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
var ApprovalContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

      var ApprovalContract = new Web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);
```

With just one of them:

```
var ApprovalContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);
```

And then again above that you also have multiple definitions of `web3` variable which are overwriting each other. Resolve this issue also, you need to end up with one `web3` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating that you have not defined the abi variable. You can define this in the html file or a separate file.

Say, you defined this in a separate js file called contractAbi.js.
You need to include this in the html file.

```
 <script src="contractAbi.js"></script>
```

Also, in the contractAbi.js, make sure you have

> var abi = [ ... abi array copied for the contract ...];

Post this, if you make a call

```
var ApprovalContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);
```

the code should find the abi variable.